# R dplyr: filter using different condition for different groups

Tags: r

I have a panel dataset identified by ID and year. I need to filter the dataset by variable "hours", but for different years I want to impose different standards on hours.

This is what I am trying to do, but since `if` is not compatible with vectors, the following codes do not work

```
data <- data %>%
           filter(
             if(year == 2014 | year == 2016){
               (hours >= 35 & hours <= 105) 
             }else if (year == 2012){
               (hours >= 30 & hours <= 100) 
             }
           )
```

A similar question is how to do the filtering only for certain years and ignore the rest of years.

Comment: see `?ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`

Answer (score 0):

```
data %>%
  filter((year %in% c(2014, 2016) & between(hours, 35, 105)) | (year == 2012 & between(hours, 30, 100)))
```